# What does "laser into something" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have found it in this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/platonic-love/201908/science-says-people-you-more-you-know).

> Maybe you're centered and at peace with yourself, secure that you have value to bring to the conversation. Or perhaps, you're **lasering into** an almost imperceptible social guffaw you committed, convinced that your conversation partner would rather undergo surgery of the Achilles tendon than talk to you.

Also I cannot understand the what **commit a social guffaw** mean. Could you explain that too?

Answer (score 3):

I think " Laser into " is a slang phrasal verb , and depend on what I saw on http://onlineslangdictionary.com it means " to focus intensely on something ".
The writer gives the word a sense of action when you point into something by the laser, you will turn turn immediately to focus on the place of the point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a particularly idiomatic phrase, but judging from both the context and the surface meaning one can guess *lasering into* means something akin to *concentrating* or *focusing on*. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laser) lists:

> Definition of laser:
>
> something resembling a laser beam in accuracy, speed, or intensity

I'm assuming the author has turned the noun into a verb, and what's similar to a laser beam is the focus with which the addressee of the article treats their social misstep.

A *social guffaw* seems like a malapropism of *gaffe* - perhaps intentional for comedic/literary effect.